Square-free numbers sum Inequality
Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $k$ be a fixed positive integer. Consider all integers  $N_1, N_2, \dots, N_r$ less than or equal to $n$ that are square-free and have exactly $2k$ distinct prime factors. For each $N_j$, choose a factorization $N_j = P_j Q_j$, where $P_j$ and $ Q_j$ are square-free numbers with exactly $k$ distinct prime factors each, satisfying $Q_j > P_j$.
Define the sum:
$$
S = \sum_{j=1}^r N_j.
$$
Conjecture:
It is always possible to choose factorizations of $P_j$ and $Q_j$ such that the following inequality holds:
$$
\sqrt{n} \cdot \sum_{j=1}^r P_j \leq S.
$$

My Question:
What techniques could be used to rigorously prove the inequality? Specifically:

Does the strategy of minimizing $P_j$ (to maximize $Q_j$) always ensure that the inequality holds? Note that we have $Q_j > \sqrt{N_j}$ for all $j$, but not necessarily $Q_j > \sqrt{n}$. For instance, consider $n=30$ and $N_j = 2\cdot 3$.
Are there known probabilistic, combinatorial, or analytic methods that might establish the validity of this conjecture?

Any insights into related problems, similar results, or counterexamples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What makes you believe the conjecture? What evidence do you have for it?

I have verified it for small values of $n$ and $k$ and it always holds. Furthermore, it seems reasonable; as $n$ grows, setting each $P_j$ the minimum possible, the proportion of the number of $Q_j > \sqrt{n}$ versus the number of $Q_j < \sqrt{n}$ becomes increasingly larger, so the conjecture strenghtens.
